# UV map appears as circular shape instead of conical shape on UV editor

Tags: uv

[image][image]i am trying to make unwrap to this conical plastic pot, it coming like this shape instead of normal layout for conical label. anyone can help me in this issue thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: what do you mean by normal layout? maybe share your file so that we give a try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @RayMairlot hi dear, title is edited .

Comment: @moonboots i added another picture to explain more my issue

Comment: did you apply scale?

Comment: @ShantanuAryan actually i didn't before i saw your comment, but  now  i did and it works perfectly. thank you very much.